# Sqlalchemy keep alive or reconnect Sessions after timeout

Tags: python, mysql, database, sqlalchemy, orm

I am trying to understand how best to keep alive or reconnect SQLAlchemy DB Sessions after they go stale due to MySQL `wait_timeout` expiring.

I am setting a low wait timeout to illustrate the issue below:

```
mysql> SET @@GLOBAL.wait_timeout = 2;
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.00 sec)

mysql> show global variables like 'wait_timeout';
+---------------+-------+
| Variable_name | Value |
+---------------+-------+
| wait_timeout  | 2     |
+---------------+-------+
1 row in set (0.01 sec)
```

Here's the error that I am seeing

```py
In [1]: sess.query(SomeTable).first()
Out[1]: <SomeTable(id=1)>
In [2]: import time

In [3]: time.sleep(4)

In [4]: sess.query(SomeTable).first()
OperationalError: (MySQLdb._exceptions.OperationalError) (2013, 'Lost connection to MySQL server during query')
```

Here's one way to prevent the error

```py
In [1]: sess.query(SomeTable).first()
Out[1]: <SomeTable(id=1)>

In [2]: sess.close()

In [3]: import time

In [4]: time.sleep(4)

In [5]: sess.query(SomeTable).first()
Out[5]: <SomeTable(id=1)>
```

Here's how I am creating the db session

```py
sess = sessionmaker(binds={
    DeclarativeBase: create_engine(
        db_config.url,
        pool_recycle=3600,
        pool_pre_ping=True,
    )},
```

A few questions:

1. The `pool_pre_ping` argument seems to make no difference to the Session object. This seems to be because SQLAlchemy runs the connection test when a [new connection is checked out from the pool](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/14/core/pooling.html#:%7E:text=The%20%E2%80%9Cpre%20ping,error%20last%20received.). I am guessing that the session object checks out a new connection soon after it is created, but does not check if the connection is alive for every query. Is my understanding correct?
2. The only way to prevent the session timeout [seems to be to call close](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23747742/sqlalchemy-session-reconnect#comment90900825_48902018) `sess. close()` soon after the query is fired. Calling `sess. close()` seems to reset the connection, so the next time I call `sess. query` a new connection seems to be checked out from the pool. Is there a better way to do this?
3. How could I keep the session that bound to the DB ORM instances returned from my query alive for longer? `obj = db.query(SomeTable).first(); time.sleep(10); obj.access_some_db_relationship`

Comment: Keeping session lifetimes short is recommended - see [the docs](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/14/orm/session_basics.html#when-do-i-construct-a-session-when-do-i-commit-it-and-when-do-i-close-it).  Why do your sessions have to stay open and idle for so long?

Comment: I have a long-running cronjob that fires db queries in a loop and does some processing thereafter. Should I be initiating a new session for each loop?